# How to stop windows console cursors from blinking

Tags: windows, cmd, console, text-cursor

I know how to completely hide a cursor,
But is their any way to just stop it from blinking?
It's oddly disturbing...

I'm not gonna install 3rd party software for this,
what I want is simple solution using few lines of C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `Run` prompt (<kbd>Win+R</kbd>)

Paste into Open box:

```
control main.cpl keyboard
```

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> Keyboard properties dialog appears.

Set **Cursor blink rate** to **None**. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>

Comment: Now every single blinking cursors are gone from my PC lmao

Answer (score 3):

For the record, by **`cmd`** you can do the same

You can save this code as **`desable_cursor_blink.cmd`**, and click/run...

```bat
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00; [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]"CursorBlinkRate"="-1"
reg import %~f0
```

---

- By command line, you also can try:

  ---

```bat
%__APPDIR__%reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v CursorBlinkRate /t REG_SZ /d -1 /f
```

---